# Writing recursive enumeration function in Scheme

Tags: algorithm, recursion, scheme, lisp, enumeration

I'm writing a recursive enumeration function, and I'm having a simple error somewhere.

Here's what *should* happen:

```
(enum 1 0.5 2.5)  
> (1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5)
```

Here's the code:

```
(define enum
   (lambda (start step stop)
      (if (not (<= stop start))
          (cons start (enum (+ start step) step  stop))
          ('(stop))
          )))
```

Edit:
The error I'm getting (from Impromptu (http://impromptu.moso.com.au/)) is:

```
> (print (enum 0 0.5 2.5))  
:ERROR: position:(0) in function "enum"  
illegal function  
Trace: enum
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that your problem is in the line

```
('(stop))
```

I think you have the right idea that you want to stop executing the recursion once you've hit the end, but this isn't the way to do it.  Because you have put this in double parentheses, this is interpreted as "evaluate 'stop', then try calling it as a function."  However, `stop` isn't a function, hence the error.

To fix this, if you want to make the return value a list containing just `stop`, use the `list` function:

```
(define enum
   (lambda (start step stop)
      (if (not (<= stop start))
          (cons start (enum (+ start step) step  stop))
          (list stop)
          )))
```

Note that there is only one set of parentheses around `list stop` here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I said ('(stop)), I meant a list, with one element: the "stop" argument (== 2.5). That's why I said "<=" instead of "<". That said, for some reason changing to "()" for the else and "<" for the predicate Just Works. Can anyone say why? Thanks!

Comment: @amindfv- I figured out the problem and updated this answer - you were trying to evaluate `stop` as a function by adding extra parentheses.  I've updated my answer to reflect this; can you look over it again and see if it more accurately explains your bug?

Comment: @amindfv: you could also use [quasiquote](http://www-pu.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/cc-2002/scheme/schintro-v14/schintro_129.html) syntax: `\`(,stop)`, though `(list stop)` is clearer.